# How can I get external API proxy for Angular 8 working correctly instead of defaulting to localhost

Tags: angular, proxy, angular8

I am basically trying to run a dev Angular application so I can write and test services easier for our production NativeScript app.

It requires an external API and I have tried multiple ways to get around the CORS issue. Many references only state that I have to do the following:

```
{
  "/main-feed": {
  "target": "https://endpoint.org",
  "secure": true,
  "logLevel": "info",
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

I have gotten this proxy to work with localhost but for an external api when I hit the final endpoint `/main-feed/v1/items` it gives me back an error that states:

`GET http://localhost:4200/main-feed/v1/items 404 (Not Found)`

I have tried `/main-feed/` and `/main-feed/*`.

It would be really great if I could get this working but I understand if Angular is not built for this. I really wish it was easier for development to override CORS but I understand the risk.

Answer (score 1):

What is the full URL of your back end point?

Did you try to set up a proxy config? If not please take a look at this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

PS: don't forget the port in your target

Comment: I did but this is referencing an api that I do not control. I could setup a spring boot or some other backend but that is more effort than I want - ended up just going the nativescript only route.